# Get he mesh from the DracoLoader of ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I work on the Draco loader of ThreeJS but I encounter a problem with the loader. I actually need the mesh of the dracofile load but the mesh is not available after i load it with this code:

```
    let mesh;
    const loader = new DRACOLoader();
    loader.setDecoderPath('./Three/examples/js/libs/draco/')
    loader.load('PATHTO drc file', function(geometry) {
        var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size: 0.05 });
        material.vertexColors = false
        mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
        mesh.position.set(0, 0, -1);
    });
    console.log(mesh) // print undifined
```

I need the mesh to perform some operations do you have some clues for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading callback runs asynchronously, so the line immediately afterward runs first and the mesh is defined only later. There are many ways to manage asynchronous programming (I'd suggest https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html as an introduction) but a simple solution in this case would be to put the later code into a callback:

```
let mesh;

...

loader.load('...', (geometry) => {
  mesh = ...
  start();
});

...

function start() {
  console.log(mesh);
}
```